# Send mail with external data through PHP

Tags: php, mail-server

I looking into building a system that can read and send mails all by itself.

The mailserver already exists. All I want to do is fetch the e mail data with a php script running locally on the mailserver, store some of the data in an external database.

Then when an "event" is raised, I want to run a php script that get's some data out of the database, create a mail , and send it through the mail server.

I'm fairly new to this, so I hope the things I say make sense.

Here's my question: Is it secure enough to work this way?
Am I doing anything against "the rules" ?

Thanks

Comment: imap is a mail retrieval/management protocol. it has nothing to do with SENDING email. that's SMTP.

Comment: You're absolutely right! Changed my post.

Comment: the security stuff can't be answered. what's your security requirement? that the emails be sent? no one can meddle with the emails, etc...? "security" is not some magic potion you can sprinkle on top of code and magically make it "secure".

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing wrong in doing the things this way. Its not against the rule. But **Email Deliverability** is not guaranteed because:

1. There is no guarantee that the email you send will pass the spam filters of email providers.
2. Number of emails you send to 1 user in a day, Any spam keyword in the mail content, user marking your email as spam etc.

Basically, there are n number of reasons why your mail server might get blacklisted by email providers. 
To ensure Email Deliverability, you need to get your mail server IP whitelisted with all the email providers. (which is not easy)

I would suggest you to use **bulk email sending third party solutions** like Sendgrid, Madmimi, etc.
Refer: [Discussion on choosing email sending service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7492425/looking-for-bulk-and-transactional-email-sending-service)

Also, these services also gives statistics like open tracking, click tracking etc...